# How to change time format for Jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, timepicker

How can I change the default value of time picker which is this (9:08am) to a decimal point like this (9.08)?

```
  Rails 4.1.9
  Ruby Gems
  gem 'jquery-timepicker-rails'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
```

This is my Jquery script for my timepicker

```
 $('#setup_time').timepicker();
 $('#setup_time').timepicker("setTime", new Date());
 $('#setup_time').show();
```

Comment: Try `$('#setup_time').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H.i' });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using this timepicker [here](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)?

If so, it's going to be formatted using PHP's time format. Try this:

```
$('#setup_time').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h.i' });
```

Comment: That's just putting chrodams comment in an answer... Let's also make a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nbvp7Lfd/

Comment: @LaveLoos I didn't see his comment when I was typing out the answer.

Comment: Thank you @12hys that solved it for me that seems like it was very easy not sure why I didn't think of it that way!